# Angular build files not bundling in dist folder

Tags: javascript, angular, build, command-line-interface, bundle

I recently upgraded my Angular 4 project, to Angular 5, then Angular 6. Before, when I would run:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --aot
```

Angular would create a few bundle files in a `dist` folder such as `vendor.fa30abf0a6e84604aa92.bundle.js`. Now, however, after I run the same command, I'm getting what appear to be a bunch unoptimized files in the `dist` folder:

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt     fontawesome-webfont.ttf    main.js           runtime.js.map          Simple-Line-Icons.woff2  views-dashboard-dashboard-module-ngfactory.js
assets                   fontawesome-webfont.woff   main.js.map       Simple-Line-Icons.eot   styles.js                views-dashboard-dashboard-module-ngfactory.js.map
favicon.ico              fontawesome-webfont.woff2  polyfills.js      Simple-Line-Icons.svg   styles.js.map
fontawesome-webfont.eot  index.html                 polyfills.js.map  Simple-Line-Icons.ttf   vendor.js
fontawesome-webfont.svg  logo.png                   runtime.js        Simple-Line-Icons.woff  vendor.js.map
```

These files are large, making my website load very slowly. It takes more than 10 seconds just to download vendor.js. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you simply run `ng build --prod`?

Comment: Yes, same files.

Comment: Are you using the Angular CLI? If so, what version? If it is 6+, open the *angular.json* and find the `configurations` section and make sure the `aot` and `buildOptimizer` setting are both set to true.

Comment: In package.json: `"@angular/cli": "^6.0.7"`. In angular.json, I don't see either option! I'm guessing this is something I should have added when upgrading from Angular 4?

Comment: If you upgraded using `ng update`, then it should have been added those to the file for you. Add them to the *angular.json* file at this path: `projects/your-project/achitect/build/configurations/production`. See if that helps.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the file at that path, but I did delete the angular.json in the root and then update @angular/cli, which fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, R Richards, for the tips. I was able to fix this by manually deleting `angular.json`, then running:

```
yarn global add @angular/cli
yarn add @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```